# Unexpected frame rate on Timer callback function

Tags: windows

## Environment

- `m_timerCallbackIntervalMs` = 1
- Game system updates are done on `OnTick` function.
- Average FPS is 500.
- ProudNet version: 1.7.48971

## Questions

Due to side effects by Windows Server, FPS goes down. How can I find a cause?

- Before Windows Update, the frame rate was 480~500 (OnTick).
- After Windows Update, the frame rate became 60~65 (OnTick).
  (Reverting the Windows Update recovers the frame rate to 480~500 again.)
- This problem also occurrs on AWS EC2 m4.large Windows Server 2019. It shows 60~65 FPS. (Our exe file is same with the only difference is Windows Server environment.)

Answer (score 0):

It uses [Sleep() Win32 function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) internally. The minimum time to sleep by Sleep() (aka. time resolution) might change as Windows Update minor version changes. To fixate the minimum time to sleep, use [timeBeginPeriod()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod) function.